# Text color changing when hovering below text

Tags: html, css

I've made 2 boxes that are blue and have a white text color, and when you hover over them, the text color changes from white to blue and the box color changes from blue to white. That part works. But when I hover below the text from the box, the text color changes back to blue even though I'm still with my mouse on the box 'href'.

Have a look at my code:

```css
body {
  background: #DCDCDC
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#galaxy {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(37, 100, 165, 0.80);
  border: 1px solid rgba(37, 100, 165, 0.80);
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#galaxy:hover {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

#test {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(37, 100, 165, 0.80);
  border: 1px solid rgba(37, 100, 165, 0.80);
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#test:hover {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #F00;
}

.button-title-text {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.button-title-text:hover {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(37, 100, 165);
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="galaxy">
      <div class="button-title-text">
        <h1>Galaxy</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="test">
      <div class="button-title-text">
        <h1>test</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consolidated your code and fixed the issue.

You had identical styles for your `#galaxy` and `#test` boxes (until they're hovered). I added a class called `.box` to both of them and moved the styles to that selector.

The issue in your post was occurring because you had a `:hover` rule on the box itself and the text inside. The hover on the text was behaving as written - it was only activating when you hovered directly over the text.

To fix this, I removed the `color:` attribute from your `.button-title-text` element, allowing it to inherit the color from the `.box`.

Then I added a `.box:hover` rule that changes the text color, which takes effect when either box is hovered.

Hope this helps!

```css
body {
  background: #DCDCDC
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(37, 100, 165, 0.80);
  border: 1px solid rgba(37, 100, 165, 0.80);
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.button-title-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: rgb(37, 100, 165);
}

#test:hover {
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="galaxy" class="box">
      <div class="button-title-text">
        <h1>Galaxy</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="test" class="box">
      <div class="button-title-text">
        <h1>test</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```